# xAxis type: 'category' without stacking duplicate names?

Tags: highcharts

Creating a column chart with some dynamically populated drilldowns. For the surface level, I'm returning the top ten results of my search, some of which share a common name.

Names display as categories just fine for both the surface and drill downs when specifying xAxis type: 'category'. However, since the surface level can have duplicate names, it's stacking them be default. Is there a setting to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the solution to this issue will be to add the same category data in two separate series. I guess you add it as one series? Check demo I posted you below.

Two series:

```
  "series": [{
    "name": "Browsers",
    "colorByPoint": true,
    "data": [{
        "name": "Chrome",
        "y": 62.74,
        "drilldown": "Chrome2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Internet Explorer",
        "y": 7.23,
        "drilldown": "Internet Explorer"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "data": [{
      "name": "Chrome",
      "y": 10.57,
      "drilldown": "Chrome1"
    }]
  }]
```

One series:

```
  "series": [{
    "name": "Browsers",
    "colorByPoint": true,
    "data": [{
        "name": "Chrome",
        "y": 62.74,
        "drilldown": "Chrome2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Internet Explorer",
        "y": 7.23,
        "drilldown": "Internet Explorer"
      },
      {
        "name": "Chrome",
        "y": 10.57,
        "drilldown": "Chrome1"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Demo: 
two series - https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/h04egdu7/3/ 
one series - https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/pnj3etd4/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!